# Cannot grant execute to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, permissions

When I try to `GRANT EXECUTE ON SP_NAME TO [DOMAIN\USER_NAME]` on my database, I'm getting the error message below:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Procedure grant_safety, Line 5
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type smallint.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

This is happening in any procedure where I try to `GRANT EXECUTE` permissions; I have tried to grant to other users as well, but same error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TEST  
AS  
BEGIN  
   SELECT 1  
END
```

Comment: Does each error indicate "Line 5"?

Comment: Yes, each error indicated "Line 5"

Comment: So the GRANT EXECUTE command is line 5? Have you tried the syntax noted in MSDN: GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.myproc TO myUser?

Comment: Yes, i have tried using the MSDN syntax, but results in same error.

Comment: Could you add the stored proc definition to your question, please?

Comment: I have added a sample procedure to the question which is also throwing the same error message when i try to grant execute permissions on it. Thanks

Comment: Is grant_safety the name of one of your stored procedures?  It's mentioned in the error so if it isn't one of yours then its a system one.

Comment: There is no stored procedure with the name grant_safety in either in the user database or in system databases.

Comment: Could there be a DDL database trigger or server level trigger setup that is logging or blocking grants by design using a proc named `grant_safety`?  Keep in mind, if you are not a `sysadmin` then you might not be able to see the `grant_safety` proc when looking in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a GO on a newline between your procedure DDL and your grant statement and after the grant.